# Reading a image input stream to an array takes a long time in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Image is small (400Kb), but it takes a long time to read. The first while loop in following code takes forever many times (some cases its super fast). `Any reason for this behavior, how can I make this consistent`. This code is executed in a asyctask as shown below. Which also shows a progress dialog.

More details: I am downloading a png from a server. My objective is to get image bounds and sample it to avoid memory issues. If I just use one input stream to get the bounds I was not able to use it again to get the image. Thats why I have to create two copies. The problem is wit the while loop taking long in unpredictable fashion. Sometimes it load really fast.

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight, boolean checkLen) {
        byte[] byteArr = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        int count = 0;

        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1 ) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            baos.flush();

            InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

            /*while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                if (len != 0) {
                    if (count + len > byteArr.length) {
                        byte[] newbuf = new byte[(count + len) * 2];
                        System.arraycopy(byteArr, 0, newbuf, 0, count);
                        byteArr = newbuf;
                    }

                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, byteArr, count, len);
                    count += len;
                }
            }*/

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
           // BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1, null, options);

            if (checkLen) {
                if (options.outHeight == options.outWidth) {
                    reqWidth = (int) (reqWidth * 0.9);
                    reqHeight = reqWidth;
                } else {
                    reqWidth = (int) (reqWidth * 0.75);
                    reqHeight = (int) (reqWidth * 0.75);
                }
            }

            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                    reqHeight);
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, count, options);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2, null, options);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            int width = b.getWidth();
            int height = b.getHeight();

            // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
            float scaleWidth = ((float) reqWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) reqHeight) / height;
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            Bitmap scaled = b.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);

            b.recycle();
            b = null;
            return scaled;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
    }


protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {

            Log.w("myApp", "doInBackground");
            Bitmap bm = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            if (mode == 1 || mode == 3) {
                try {
                    URL aURL = new URL(url);
                    URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(Utils.timeout);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(Utils.timeout);
                    Log.w("myApp", "doInBackground- connect");
                    conn.connect();
                    Log.w("myApp", "doInBackground- Image Request");
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                    Log.w("myApp", "doInBackground- Image recived");
                    bm = Utils.decodeBitmapFromInputStream(is, width, width, true);
                    Log.w("myApp", "doInBackground-Decoded");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (ringProgressDialog != null && ringProgressDialog.isShowing())
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (is != null)
                            is.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            } 
            return bm;
        }
```

Comment: `InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());` any reasons for such obviously not optimal code ?

Comment: Do away with that ByteArrayOutputStream. Just use InputStream inputSteam to decode the bounds first. You ask to much memory from the memory manager. Thats why it becomes so slow.

Comment: You should tell more what you are doing and what you want. For instance what kind of file are you downloading? A .jpg? A .png?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have given more details above.

Comment: At second view i have to say that your code is quit ok. It does not need that much memory if the file is only 400 KB. But it needs double that memory in this way. Plus the memory for the bitmap.

Comment: Which while loop are you talking about? Please dont post code which is not in use.

Comment: You did not tell why you need a matrix to post scale the bitmap. Why cant you decode it right away right?

Comment: Commented out while as well as the one in use. I needed to scale because the 2nd decodeStream did not scale it to the dimensions  specified.

Comment: How do you determine that the first loop is the place where time is spent? I do not see any logging etc.

Comment: I put debug point inside the while loop, and it gets hit with a huge delay, which means the inputStream.read() is taking long